# Can I connect my LND to someone else's bitcoin node?

Tags: lightning-network, nodes

Now I am running my own Bitcoin full node on my local machine and connect to it with [LND](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd).

I see some open bitcoin nodes on https://bitnodes.io and wonder if it's ok to connect my LND not to my own node but to someone else's one? Is this possible, performant and worth it or should I run my own node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LND connects to Bitcoin Core's JSON-RPC interface, it doesn't use the peer-to-peer protocol. Thus, publicly reachable Bitcoin nodes will be useless unless they also expose the RPC interface, which they should not do anyway because it's not safe.

In any case, you should run your own node. Relying on someone else's node exposes you to attacks.